# autoplay hover after 3 second

Tags: javascript, css, autoplay

I have 5 sentences and I want after 3 seconds the next sentence's background to be colored

HTML:

```
    <div class="text-slider">
        <div class="text-wrap">
            <p class="text text-1 active"> text 1</p>
            <p class="text text-2">text 2</p>
            <p class=" text text-3">text 3</p>
            <p class="text text-4">text 4</p>
            <p class="text text-5"> text 5 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.text-wrap p.active {
  background-color: #edf0f2;
}
```

JS

```
let count = 1
setInterval(()=>{

    document.querySelector(`.text-${count}`).classList.add('active')
    count++
   
    if(count>5){
        count =1
    }
}, 3000)
```

I want to remove class active from the previous element so I try

```
 document.querySelector(`.text-${count -1}`).classList.remove('active')
```

after count++ but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding an element with relative to the count, you can hack it a bit, and in your selector find active element and remove that active class from it as follows.

```
let count = 1;
setInterval(() => {
  // Here you remove active class from `p` tag which had it
  document.querySelector(".text.active").classList.remove("active"); // <- HERE
  
  document.querySelector(`.text-${count}`).classList.add("active");
  count++;

  if (count > 5) {
    count = 1;
  }
}, 3000);
```

## Snippet

```js
let count = 1;
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector(".text.active").classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector(`.text-${count}`).classList.add("active");
  count++;

  if (count > 5) {
    count = 1;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.text-wrap p.active {
  background-color: #edf0f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-slider">
    <div class="text-wrap">
      <p class="text text-1 active">text 1</p>
      <p class="text text-2">text 2</p>
      <p class="text text-3">text 3</p>
      <p class="text text-4">text 4</p>
      <p class="text text-5">text 5</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I refactored JavaScript file a bit:

```js
let count = 1
setInterval(() => {
  if (count > 5) {
    document.querySelector(`.text-${count- 1}`).classList.remove('active')
    count = 1
  } else {
    document.querySelector(`.text-${count}`).classList.add('active')
    if (count > 1) document.querySelector(`.text-${count-1}`).classList.remove('active')
    count++
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
.text-wrap p.active {
  background-color: #edf0f2;
}
```

```html
    <div class="text-slider">
      <div class="text-wrap">
        <p class="text text-1 active"> text 1</p>
        <p class="text text-2">text 2</p>
        <p class=" text text-3">text 3</p>
        <p class="text text-4">text 4</p>
        <p class="text text-5"> text 5 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `remove` instead of `add` to delete the class, and I try to adjust your js code a little bit.

```js
let count = 1;
setInterval((storage) => {
  const clsName = 'active';
  const current = `.text-${count}`;
  const previous = storage.shift();
  document.querySelector(previous)?.classList.remove(clsName);
  document.querySelector(current).classList.add(clsName);
  storage.push(current);
  count = count % 5;
  count++;
}, 1000, [])
```

```css
.text-wrap p.active {
  background-color: #edf0f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-slider">
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <p class="text text-1 active"> text 1</p>
    <p class="text text-2">text 2</p>
    <p class="text text-3">text 3</p>
    <p class="text text-4">text 4</p>
    <p class="text text-5"> text 5 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```